# Banshee crashes consistently - is there a fix?

Tags: banshee

Since updating to ubuntu 11.10 I've had trouble with banshee. In particular when I run it I find that it crashes within an hour without fail. I get the following

```
     Unhandled Exception: System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation. ---> System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object
     at Mono.Zeroconf.Providers.AvahiDBus.BrowseService.DisposeResolver () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
     at Mono.Zeroconf.Providers.AvahiDBus.BrowseService.Dispose () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
     at Mono.Zeroconf.Providers.AvahiDBus.ServiceBrowser.OnItemRemove (Int32 interface, Protocol protocol, System.String name, System.String type, System.String domain, LookupResultFlags flags) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
     at (wrapper managed-to-native) System.Reflection.MonoMethod:InternalInvoke (System.Reflection.MonoMethod,object,object[],System.Exception&)
     at System.Reflection.MonoMethod.Invoke (System.Object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr, System.Reflection.Binder binder, System.Object[] parameters, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
    --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
    at System.Reflection.MonoMethod.Invoke (System.Object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr, System.Reflection.Binder binder, System.Object[] parameters, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
    at System.Reflection.MethodBase.Invoke (System.Object obj, System.Object[] parameters) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
    at System.Delegate.DynamicInvokeImpl (System.Object[] args) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
    at System.MulticastDelegate.DynamicInvokeImpl (System.Object[] args) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
    at System.Delegate.DynamicInvoke (System.Object[] args) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
    at NDesk.DBus.Connection.HandleSignal (NDesk.DBus.Message msg) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
    at NDesk.DBus.Connection.DispatchSignals () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
    at NDesk.DBus.Connection.Iterate () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
    at Mono.Zeroconf.Providers.AvahiDBus.DBusManager.IterateThread (System.Object o) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
```

Does anyone else also have this problem?

Comment: Have you tried deleting your banshee profile?(in ~/.config/)
Have you tried purging and then installing it again?
Have you tried using banshee ppa, for daily updates? (in https://launchpad.net/banshee)
Another way of solving this might be: checking the modules, where the problems occurs. It looks like the main problem is within mono, so checking packages such as mono-zeroconf (reinstalling, updating)
There's a lot of ways of solving this problem and I don't think it necessarily need a patch

Comment: If all fails consider using another app while waiting for a fix!

Answer (score 2):

Remove ~/.cache/banshee*:

`rm -rf ~/.cache/banshee*`

And run Banshee again. It should not crash now.

Comment: Didn't work :( It started crashing after enabled BPR or something